# pandas time delta from grouped neighbors

Tags: python, pandas

I have a group of dates.  I would like to subtract them from their forward neighbor to get the delta between them. My  code look like this:

```
import pandas, numpy, StringIO


txt = '''ID,DATE
002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16,2003-08-13 00:00:00
002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16,2003-08-13 00:00:00
0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33,2006-05-07 00:00:00
0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33,2006-06-03 00:00:00
00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a,2006-03-09 00:00:00
00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a,2006-03-09 00:00:00
0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e,2007-10-13 00:00:00
0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e,2007-10-27 00:00:00
0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc,2001-02-01 00:00:00
0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc,2008-01-20 00:00:00
'''
df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(txt))
df = df.sort('DATE')
df.DATE = pandas.to_datetime(df.DATE)
grouped = df.groupby('ID')
df['X_SEQUENCE_GAP'] = pandas.concat([g['DATE'].sub(g['DATE'].shift(), fill_value=0) for title,g in grouped])
```

I am getting pretty incomprehensible results. So, I am going to go with I have a logic error.

The results I get are as follows:

```
                               ID                DATE       X_SEQUENCE_GAP
0  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00 12277 days, 00:00:00
1  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00             00:00:00
3  0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33 2006-06-03 00:00:00    27 days, 00:00:00
2  0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33 2006-05-07 00:00:00 13275 days, 00:00:00
5  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00 13216 days, 00:00:00
4  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00             00:00:00
6  0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e 2007-10-13 00:00:00 13799 days, 00:00:00
7  0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e 2007-10-27 00:00:00    14 days, 00:00:00
9  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2008-01-20 00:00:00  2544 days, 00:00:00
8  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2001-02-01 00:00:00 11354 days, 00:00:00
```

I was expecting for exapme that 0 and 1 would have both a 0 result. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the error is not incomprehensible for someone. Posting the error  could help us more.

Comment: upgrade to 0.11.0rc1, and take a look at the new docs, and these recipes: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#miscellaneous, guessing you are using 0.10.1, lots of good changes in timedeltas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in 0.11rc1 (I don't think will work on a prior version)
When you shift dates the first one is a NaT (like a nan, but for datetimes/timedeltas)

```
In [27]: df['X_SEQUENCE_GAP'] = grouped.apply(lambda g: g['DATE']-g['DATE'].shift())

In [30]: df.sort()
Out[30]: 
                                 ID                DATE      X_SEQUENCE_GAP
0  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00                 NaT
1  002691c9cec109e64558848f1358ac16 2003-08-13 00:00:00            00:00:00
2  0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33 2006-05-07 00:00:00                 NaT
3  0088f218a1f00e0fe1b94919dc68ec33 2006-06-03 00:00:00   27 days, 00:00:00
4  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00                 NaT
5  00d34668025906d55ae2e529615f530a 2006-03-09 00:00:00            00:00:00
6  0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e 2007-10-13 00:00:00                 NaT
7  0101d3286dfbd58642a7527ecbddb92e 2007-10-27 00:00:00   14 days, 00:00:00
8  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2001-02-01 00:00:00                 NaT
9  0103bd73af66e5a44f7867c0bb2203cc 2008-01-20 00:00:00 2544 days, 00:00:00
```

You can then fillna (but you have to do this ackward type conversion becuase of a numpy bug, will get fixed in 0.12).

```
 In [57]: df['X_SEQUENCE_GAP'].sort_index().astype('timedelta64[ns]').fillna(0)
Out[57]: 
0              00:00:00
1              00:00:00
2              00:00:00
3     27 days, 00:00:00
4              00:00:00
5              00:00:00
6              00:00:00
7     14 days, 00:00:00
8              00:00:00
9   2544 days, 00:00:00
Name: X_SEQUENCE_GAP, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```